# What are the values of the (photopic) CIE 1924 luminous efficiency function?

Tags: units, photometry

Apparently, the luminous flux and therefore indirectly the lumen (lm), one of the 7 basic SI units, is defined in terms of "the" 1924 luminous effiency function $\overline{y}(\lambda)$ of the CIE, which is itself a dimensionless function of wavelength. More precisel, the luminous flux $\Phi_v$ is defined as

$$\Phi_v = 683.002 (lm/W) \cdot \int_0^\infty d\lambda \cdot \overline{y}(\lambda) \Phi_e(\lambda),$$

where $\Phi_e(\lambda)$ is the spectral radiant flux.

**Now my question simply is, how is this function $\overline{y}(\lambda)$ defined?** I have found one website having some values for a similar curve, but it does not seem to "the official one". So my question is really about that particular curve that defines the luminous flux.